# Installing node 7 on Centos machine

Tags: node.js, centos, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to install node 7 on my Centos machine because previous versions do not support the apn protocol for sending iOS notifications. So I tried to execute:

```
sudo yum install nodes
```

and both npm and node were installed but unfortunately the latter of version v6.10.0.

```
sudo npm install latest
```

changes nothing.
I found [a post](https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-and-npm-on-centos/) suggesting to update the rpm repository, but that changes nothing; I even tried to change the command to:

```
sudo curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
```

but when I tried to install node again, still the 6.10 version came out.

How may I force npm to adopt node7 as the stable or latest version?
Or what other way there exists to install node 7 instead of 6.10 for the good?

Comment: This one probably belongs on server fault not SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (Node Version manager). First remove node and npm, then :

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash

source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

nvm install 7
nvm use 7
```

Then check version with :

```
node -v
nvm ls
```

Comment: Yes in fact I installed nvm instead of npm and after a few problems now I have node 7. Hoping it stands there....
In fact it was enough to use: nvm install latest